# Using Foundation CSS in a JavaFX application

Tags: java, css, javafx, zurb-foundation

I am creating a GUI in JavaFX using FXML. I want to use [ZURB Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) to style the GUI. Is this possible?

Comment: Foundation is for HTML and you cannot use it with JavaFX. The only way would to build a HTML UI using Foundation and show it in the JavaFX [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html).

Comment: Some of the foundation html css elements were [ported to JavaFX CSS elements](https://github.com/devork/golan).  See also: [Foundation Style CSS for JavaFX](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2490009)

Answer (score 4):

ZURB Foundation can only be used to style HTML pages. Since JavaFX is vastly different from websites, CSS stylesheets cannot be interchanged between them.

If you are looking for a different style than the default one, maybe you will enjoy one of these instead:

- [JFoenix](http://jfoenix.com/) (material design)

  [image]
- [Flatter](http://www.guigarage.com/flatter/) (flat design)

  [image]
- [AeroFX](http://www.guigarage.com/aerofx/) (Windows 7 Aero design)

  [image]
- [AquaFX](http://www.guigarage.com/aquafx/) (Mac OSX design)

  [image]
- [JMetro](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/category/metro/) (Windows 8/10 flat metro style)

  [image] [image]

Note that these images just resemble a quick peek at what the style looks like. All of these projects have more to offer than just the shown control(s).